# Animate plot containing both bar and line plots using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have data of this format:

```
head(data)
year    price   profit
2018    3185.96   9
2017    3249.69   10
2016    3005.24   6
2015    3739.79   17
2014    2238.22   15
```

I want get the price variable as bar and profit as line with year as x-axis and animate the plot using gganimate. I can plot a static plot of both the variables using 2 y axis this way :

```
p1 <- ggplot(data) + geom_bar(aes(year, price, fill = year), stat = 'identity') +
  geom_line(aes(year, profit*100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Price',sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, 'Profit%'))
```

[image]
or have a facet grid this way:

```
long <- pivot_longer(data, -year, names_to = 'Category', values_to = 'Value')

p2 <- ggplot(long, aes(year, Value)) + facet_grid(Category~., scales = 'free') +
  geom_bar(data = long[long$Category == 'price', ], stat = 'identity') +
  geom_line(data = long[long$Category == 'profit', ])
```

The problem is that I am unable animate either of the plots using `gganimate` such that past values/bars are shown in the plot as it progresses through the `year` variable.

If I use `transition_time` or `transition_states` along with `shadow_mark`, I am unable to plot the line, whereas if I use `transition_reveal` to get the line, the past years bars are fading away.

[image]

I need to have both the bar and line progressing  through `years` while retaining the past values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what you're looking for is `transition_manual()`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

data %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, price, fill = year)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  geom_line(aes(year, profit*100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Price',
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, 'Profit%')) + 
  transition_manual(year, cumulative = TRUE)
```

[image]